# javascript Whats wrong with this code

Tags: javascript

my textarea and all its atributes is correct, but my javascript not right cannot set value of oTextbox3.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Retrieving a Textbox Value Example</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txt2"></textarea> <br /> <textarea rows="5"  cols="25" name="txt3"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Set Values" onclick="setValues()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setValues() { 
      var oTextbox2= document.getElementById("txt2");
      oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.value; oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.split(" ");
      oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.sort();

      var oTextbox3 = document.getElementById("txt3"); 
      oTextbox3.value = oTextbox2;
      } 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: a good practice is to not change the type of a variable so if you declared (and even named) a var to be `oTextBox2` you shouldn't change it to its value and than an array of words.

Comment: also you can do all this in a single line: `oTextbox2.value.split(" ").sort();`

Comment: thanks for input, i just started javascript and i see that simplicity is the key when coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `oTextbox3.value = oTextbox2.value`?

And if you're using `getElementById`, then you need to use `id`, not `name`.

EDIT: Or use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName):

```
var oTextbox2 = document.getElementsByName('txt2')[0];
```

Comment: it is easy to set value of textarea has an id atribute, but i dont know how to retrieve value of textarea if it only has a name attribute.

Comment: my final code with your help, works perfect. thank you      <body>
 <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txt2"></textarea>
 <br />
 <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="txt3"></textarea>
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Set Values" onclick="setValues()" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function setValues() {
   var oTextbox2= document.getElementsByName("txt2")[0];   
   oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.value;
   oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.split(" ");
   oTextbox2 = oTextbox2.sort();

   var oTextbox3 = document.getElementsByName("txt3")[0]; 
   oTextbox3.value = oTextbox2;
 } 
 </script>
</body>

Comment: the idea is to sort everything in alphabetical order, when i use id, it works perfect, but when i use the name attribute it does not work

Answer (score 2):

You use `document.getElementById` but assign `name`s to your DOM elements. Use `id` attributes instead:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="25" id="txt2"></textarea> <br /> <textarea rows="5"  cols="25" id="txt3"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

**document.getElementById("txt3")** will get the element by "ID", you used **name="txt3"** you should have use **id="txt3"** in your textarea